# Is there a name for this kind of space?

Tags: terminology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetry

Assume a Riemannian symmetric space $G/H$ where the decomposition of the Lie algebra of $G$ is $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{h} \oplus \mathfrak{m}$. It is a known fact that if $\mathfrak{h}$ is the Lie algebra of $H$ then

$$
[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{h}]\subset \mathfrak{h}], \quad [\mathfrak{h}, \mathfrak{m}] \subset \mathfrak{m},\quad [\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}] \subset \mathfrak{h}.
$$
Is there a special name to call the spaces $G/H$ where the stronger condition

$$
[\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}] = \mathfrak{h}
$$
holds? Or a name for such decomposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decomposition with the stronger condition is called *effective*. It appears in connection with
*pseudo-Riemannian symmetric spaces*, where one deals with a special case of the symmetric decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus \mathfrak{m}$, namely that the decomposition is *effective*, i.e., that it is *minimal*, which precisely means that $[\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}] = \mathfrak{h}$, and that $\mathfrak{h}$ does not contain a non-trivial ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$. For details see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=AL56H5pF3akC&pg=PA706&lpg=PA706&dq=Riemannian+symmetric+space+G/H+Lie+algebra+decomposition+with+[m,m]%3Dh&source=bl&ots=1cDdnd4RTA&sig=N4-zcI84OJAAKgQ7RCSd_tELxV4&hl=de&sa=X&ei=_ONeVbrVLcSuUYCegLAF&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Riemannian%20symmetric%20space%20G%2FH%20Lie%20algebra%20decomposition%20with%20[m%2Cm]%3Dh&f=false).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is very helpful, and just what I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome !